# After running mongo --repair database is empy

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

On my developer machine I've reinstalled ubuntu and just copied files to /data/db from my old install.

After mongo --repair which seemingly went normal (no error messages or such)  I see no databases I'm expecting to see.

How can I repair my database?

Here the first part of the log file:

```
Thu Dec  6 17:55:21 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2123 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=sog
Thu Dec  6 17:55:21 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.2, pdfile version 4.5
Thu Dec  6 17:55:21 [initandlisten] git version: d1b43b61a5308c4ad0679d34b262c5af9d664267
Thu Dec  6 17:55:21 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Thu Dec  6 17:55:21 [initandlisten] options: { repair: true }
Thu Dec  6 17:55:21 [initandlisten] Unable to check for journal files due to: boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator constructor: No such file or directory: "/data/db/journal"
Thu Dec  6 17:55:21 [initandlisten] ****
Thu Dec  6 17:55:21 [initandlisten] ****
Thu Dec  6 17:55:21 [initandlisten] need to upgrade database fan-fiction with pdfile version 4.5, new version: 4.5
Thu Dec  6 17:55:21 [initandlisten]      starting upgrade
Thu Dec  6 17:55:21 [initandlisten]  fan-fiction repairDatabase fan-fiction
Thu Dec  6 17:55:21 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_1/fan-fiction.ns, filling with zeroes...
Thu Dec  6 17:55:21 [FileAllocator] creating directory /data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_1/_tmp
Thu Dec  6 17:55:21 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_1/fan-fiction.ns, size: 16MB,  took 0.001 secs
Thu Dec  6 17:55:21 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_1/fan-fiction.0, filling with zeroes...
```

Comment: You probably didn't need to run a `--repair` could you see them before you did a `--repair`? Also is mongodb actually pointing to `/data/db`?

Comment: @Sammaye I see them from filesystem not from mongo. And from the looks of the logs (I've modified the post) it looks in this directory too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've copied files under root and forgot to chown them. Now everything works like charm.